# Port redirect through iptables to kvm machine (Windows server)

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, port, forwarding

I have a dedicated server Kimsufi Ks-3 with stock kernel and KVM virtualization.

I have installed windows server on a kvm guest, and I'm trying to redirect a port from host machine to the rdp windows port (3389). For do than I have used iptables with this commands:

```
root@ns370482:~# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.208:3389
root@ns370482:~# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.208:3389
```

> 192.168.100.208 is the guest Windows Server.

When I try to connect trough host machine with remmina to te private ip it works, but when I try from the public IP of the server with publicip:2222, it doesn't work.

```
root@ns370482:~# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.100.208:3389
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:2222 to:192.168.100.208:3389

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3389
MASQUERADE  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:3389
```

What I'm doing wrong?